uwsgi has not killed and became zombie, when stop by max-requests
I have problem...
I set up configuration property 'max-requests'.
When server receive requests at max-requests,
uwsgi tell 'The work of process PID is done. Seeya!' and respawn worker at now
But, my uwsgi became zombie process....
service   232327  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Nov05   0:06 [uwsgi] <defunct>
So i configure 'vaccum', but it is not solution
how do i can solve this problem....
This is my uwsgi configuration and I run server with django.
[uwsgi]
virtualenv = /home/service/service/.venv
socket = /tmp/uwsgi_sock
pidfile2=/tmp/service.pid

module=project.wsgi
callable=application

master=true
processes=1
threads=2
max-requests=2500
harakiri=15
lazy-apps=true
vaccum=true

logto=/var/log/service/uwsgi.log
log-maxsize = 32428800
enable-threads = true

ignore-write-errors=true
ignore-sigpipe=true
disable-write-exception=true

I add configure 'vaccum'...
and harakiri short....
but above harakiri seconds, process still zombieyour text
